# Is it possible to get the integral very small for a finite measure?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measurable space and $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$. Let $g$ be a nonnegative, integrable function.

Is it then possible to choose for any $\varepsilon > 0$ a constant $K_{\varepsilon}>0$ so that

$\int_{\left\{g\geq K_{\varepsilon}\right\}}g\, d\mu<\varepsilon/2$?

Comment: Have you seen http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Measure-theoretic_statement ?

Comment: Yes, but I did not come along with that. How can I use that here?

Comment: Define $g_n(x)=g(x)$ if $g(x)\le n$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $g_n\nearrow g$. So $\int g_n\rightarrow \int g$. So $\int g-g_n\rightarrow 0$, which gives what you want.

Comment: Oh, I do not understand. Where is the constant?--- And why does from this follow my desired estimation?

Comment: $\int g-g_n = \int_{[g>n]} g$. So, given $\epsilon>0$,  you can choose $N$ so that $\int_{[g\ge N]} g<\epsilon/2$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you very much!

Comment: One question still remains: Where does one need that $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$?

Comment: The assumption that $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$ is not needed.

Comment: A bit more straightforward: $g_n=g\cdot\chi_{[g\ge n]}$ converges a.e. to $0$ and is dominated by the integrable function $g$. So $\int_{[g\ge n]} g\rightarrow 0$ by the Lebesque Dominated Convergence theorem..

Comment: @DavidMitra I use the task here in the task http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617260/uniform-integrability-show-an-equivalence. There is the condition that $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$. But I do not see where I need it there...

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. For any $\epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that
   $$
   \mu(A) < \delta \Rightarrow \int_A gd\mu < \epsilon
   $$
2. Chebyshev's inequality, which states that
   $$
   \mu(\{x \in \Omega : g(x) \geq t\}) \leq \frac{1}{t}\int_{\Omega} gd\mu
   $$